# Android emulator does not install app when using 'ionic emulate android' command

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and Android programming, so I am sorry if there are any inconveniences.

My problem is that I can't see my app (default app in tutorial) on the emulated android virtual device. It just shows a stock android phone basically after I run `ionic emulate android`. So I assume the app wasn't installed on the emulator.

It builds the apk but doesn't do anything with it it seems.
I think I installed everythink correctly:

```
> duc@duc-ThinkPad-T450s:~/myApp$ ionic info Your system information:
> Cordova CLI: 6.0.0 Ionic Version: 1.2.4 Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
> Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0 OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:
> Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Node Version: v4.4.1
```

I hope you could help me out, just wanted to get the tutorial going :)

Greets, Duc

**Edit**:

> I finally managed to install the apk manually to the emulated device
>   using this command:
>
> ```
>  adb -s <your emulator> install </your/apk/path>
> ```
>
> However installing it manually is very inconvenient and annoying. 
>   Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem solved! 
You have to write in the commandline:

```
android avd
```

Then a menu pops up and you have to create your own avd, then **start** it

Then you need to open a new terminal (ctrl+alt+t).
Cd to the right path of your app.

Now `ionic emulate android` should work.

Comment: This is not an "answer".  You should edit your original post and add this information.

Comment: It took me 3 days to realise this, so embarassing. However thanks for the help guys! What an awesome community :)

Comment: @D.Phi for emulate Android with specify virtual device you can use `ionic emulate --target=avdName android` where avdName is virtual device name in AVD Manager

Comment: For ionic 3 the new command is `ionic cordova emulate android`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use third-party emulator like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) (which works much faster).

Use `ionic build android` and just drag build APK `/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk` to Genymotion emulator.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail! Thanks for your response. I used an emulator accelerator on ubuntu so there is no difference in perfomance in comparison to Genymotion. However it is much more convenient to drag in the build apk! And Genymotion has some nice features too. Now I am using Genymotion! Thanks for your answer, although the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: @D.Phi I am glad it helped! Make sure to select the answer which was the most helpful to you as future readers will also find it useful. And, your CPU is Intel or AMD ? This problem can occur when using CPU AMD as it does not support virtualization Intel HAXM